# R get element from a predefined function

Tags: r, subset

I am running a script with a predefined function that calculates a couple of by products before giving me the desired end result. Now I wanted to 'grep' some of these by products as I need them for further calculation.

I thought the normal way to do that is to call an element(say, t) within function f as f$t. However, in case I do get the error object of type closure is not subsetable. Is there some way to stillextract out of the function?

Thanks

Comment: These variables a "local" to the function. They exist only in the function's environment and are lost after evaluation. You should have your function return them together with the main result in a list or as attributes.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't write the function myself so could you suggest any way how I could alter that function so that these intermediate results are returned as well?

Comment: You could try checking the code, copying it and make it return those elements. However I have no experience in this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function might be useful

Comment: If you don't want to copy the functions code, you can use `trace` to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access local variables in the function, but you can return them as needed.

For instance if you have:

```
myfunct <- function(x, y)
      {
      val1 <- x + y
      val2 <- x - y
      result <- val1 * val2

      return(result)
      }
```

The only thing you have access to is the final result.
If you want to have access to `val1` and `val2` you can do:

```
myfunct <- function(x, y)
      {
      val1 <- x + y
      val2 <- x - y
      result <- val1 * val2

      return(list(res=result, valsum=val1, valdiff=val2))
      }
```

You can now do:

```
test <- myfunct(10, 20)
print(test$valsum)
print(test$valdiff)
print(test$res)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a better way to output the local variables of a function into the global environment. R provides a special assignment operator which comes in handy here.

> myfunct <- function(x, y)
>         {

```
  val1 <<- x + y
  val2 <<- x - y
  result <- val1 * val2

  return(result)
  }
```

please notice the extra character in the assignment operator. what this does is that the variables val1 and val2 are assigned in the global environment and at the same time you can use it to calculate the result. you just return the result from the function. you can go ahead and play around with val1 and val2 in the global environment.

**Edit after few comments :** I agree that in general this will not be a good feature. but you have to understand the requirements of the question. my understanding was that there is a pre-written function which is being used which already has a form. now in such a case a lot of times you would want to debug the function without wanting to change the form of the function.

so without touching what the function is returning, if you want to output an internal variable, then this feature of R comes in very handy. but i agree, before you close R for the day, make sure you have removed all instances of this operator.

Comment: This is another method but I am not so sure it is a *better* method. Overwriting global environment from a function is generally bad practice: you may very easily forget that your function modifies the global environment, then use `val1` and `val2` thinking they had not been changed. Also, you may have name conflicts. So, as a general rule, this is not the optimal solution, especially for long scripts.

Comment: Another advantage of returning a list is that you can do: `res1 <- myfunct(10,20)`, then `res2 <- myfunct(30,50)` and you can have `res1$val1` and `res2$val1` separately, which you could not have by using global variables.